# Code First Detect Changes Navigation Property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity

I'm using EF 6.0 with code first approach.

I've a primary entity, "Person" with a reference property "Address".

When I execute code like this:

```
Person.Address = new Address();
var state = dbContenxt.Entry(Person).State
```

The state variable is Unmodified.

Is it due to code first approach?
If I use the same code with db first, all works fine and state variable results as expected, that is Modified.

Comment: Can you show your mapping classes?

Comment: Is Address an Entity or just a Class?

Answer (score 0):

I anwer my question by myself.
I've repoduced the issue:

### if you add an Association through toolbox by selecting Association item, visual studio will create an association without foreign key on Person entity class.

```
Person Entity:
Id
Name
Address (Address is navigation property)
--------------
Address Entity:
Id
Location
Person (Person is a navigation property)
```

Instead, if you add an Association by right click on Address class, then Visual Studio will show you a modal window where by default, foreign key will be added on your entity. By the way, 
your entity state will result Modified.

```
Person Entity:
Id
Name
Address_Id -> Foreign Key, all changes will be properly tracked.
Address (Address is navigation property)
--------------
Address Entity:
Id
Location
Person (Person is a navigation property)
```

However, both of procedures will save all changes.

Comment: Yes, It's a navigation property.

Comment: No, I'm sorry but it's rilevant for sure. Please, try by yourself. If you map an association with foreignKey like my sample, your entity state will result Modified, otherwise it doesn't

Comment: OK, that's because relationship fixup now alters the primitive FK property, which changes the object state. But you should change the wording of your question to make this answer relevant to it. Don't use the words "complex type", that's a totally different concept.